# saving data in array codeginiter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm saving my data with Array, look:

Get data:

```
$data['address'] = $this->input->post('address');
```

Save:

```
$this->load->model('mymodel');
if($this->inscricao_model->mymodel($data)){
echo "success";
}
```

But now, I'll have another field (checkbox) with names as array, how to I save this information?
My check box:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" id"skill" />
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" id"skill" />
```

I was trying, but generate a error:

```
$data['skills'] = $this->input->post('skills');

Message: Array to string conversion
```

Comment: what type is `$this->input->post('skills')` could you post `var_dump($this->input->post('skills'))`

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "testss" [1]=> string(7) "tessssst" }` @dm03514

Comment: Your checkbox is multi select type or single select?

Comment: There is a multiple selection so it returns array so you have to take loop to get values from array.

Comment: Yes, but how I do in this case? I'm trying but not work. @srbhbarot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use values of checkbox like this:

```
foreach( $this->input->post('skills') as $r )
{
    echo $r;
}
```

Edit:
You can do something like this:

```
    $i=1;
    foreach( $this->input->post('skills') as $r )
    {
        $data['field'.$i]= $r;
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: but I want save each checkbox data in a diferent column in my database. this way I print everything together. @srbhbarot